# Unity3D OnPointerClick is based on cam position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I'm completely lost on how to approach this problem. I have a implementation of `IPointerClickHandler` that goes something like this :

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name);

    //Othe rstuff
}
```

So at least every object with this attached to it should print out its name to the console. Now I have 2 screenshot to further Explain the Problem.
[image: RayCast fails here]

The two tiles with the lilipop and the briefcase do not fire OnPointerClick  when the camera is in this position.

[image: RayCast is Ok here]

Move the cam a bit to the right and the event is firec correcrtly.

What have I checked/tried:
Nothing is blocking the object
The camera has a 2D Physics Ray caster attached to it. Its layers are correct.
The tiles have BoxCollider2Ds.
 Edit: Did a simple raycast test; THis is the code attached to the camera. This hits from any position as long as even part of the collider is vissible on screen. While if even a part of the collider is near the edge of the viewport or outside of it. OnPointerClick does not work. How do I solve this?

```
public class RayCasterTest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(pos, Vector2.up, 0.0f);
        if (hit.collider != null)
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The raycast code is always working but the `OnPointerClick` is not when the camera is moved?

Comment: OnPointerClick does not work when the camera is in a specific position. Testing showed me that if the edge of the box2d collider is near or outside the viewport OnPointerClick does not fire.

Comment: Never had that type of problem before with `OnPointerClick`. Is your camera rotation 0,0,0? Also  make sure that the Canvas mode is set to Screen Space Overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so how do I explain this. I have a big 2dBoxcollider behind everything. I use it as camera bounds. Now for some reason from time to time the EventSystem would hit it and not the correct collider that is definitely on top if it. Setting this collider to a layer excluded from the Physics3d raycaster seems to have fixed the problem.